# What is wrong with my MySQL CASE/WHEN syntax?

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I'm trying to learn the ropes of some new MySQL syntax and am having trouble.  This should be simple...

I'm following along with the manual here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html

but I keep getting a syntax error.  Here is my routine:

```
# Drop anonymous accounts, if any
USE mysql;
CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE User = '' AND Host = 'localhost') 
 WHEN 1 THEN
  DROP USER ''@'localhost';
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
END CASE;
```

The error is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE User = ''
>   AND Host = 'localhost')

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing your comment regarding the fixed statement but immediate second issue, it was clear that you're not using this within a stored procedure or function. The documentation for [`flow control statements`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flow-control-statements.html) very subtly states that they need to be within stored procedures/functions.

Update your code to be within a procedure, and then just call the procedure to execute:

```
USE mysql;

DROP PROCEDURE p;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE p() BEGIN
    CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE User = '' AND Host = 'localhost') 
        WHEN 1 THEN
            DROP USER ''@'localhost';
            FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
        ELSE
            SELECT 'no users found!';
    END CASE;
END;
|

CALL p();
```

Also note that I added a catch-all `ELSE` block; if you don't catch the value, `CASE` will throw a "Case not found" warning - which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: OK, you got the CASE/WHEN syntax working!  Now the DROP USER ''@'localhost'; is throwing a syntax error?  This is should be simple...?

Comment: @AdamFriedman Ah - I see the real issue now, it's a completely different problem, which actually means your original `CASE`-statement was correct. You're not using the `CASE` inside a procedure or function - which is a requirement. I'll update my answer to reflect.

Comment: Your solution works.  Down the rabbit hole I go.  Now I have to learn about stored procedures.  Thanks so much for getting me here -- I think. ;)